# Admob Using test device after exporting

Tags: android, admob

Before 2 years i got suspended while testing live ads while coding, I am happy that i got my admob account back now. So this time i want to be sure i am doing right steps.

**1)** For testing i used the google reference **banner_ad_unit_id**

**2)** I know i can use either my device ID or emulator too using

```
AdRequest.Builder addTestDevice (String deviceId);
```

**3)** But do i need to comment this before exporting, After exporting will they suspend if i view live ads on my own device or i need to keep all my device in the testing list?

**4)** If thats the condition, if somebody who don't like me hit my Ads 50 times, will they suspend my account again?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep `addTestDevice` in release as well if you want and if you test your app in release mode you probably should do that so you won't end up with the account closed again by clicking your own adds :).

If someone clicks that much on your ads then you might have to contact the admob team if they will disable your account even though I don't think it'll happen.